# Disable or remove "Assign to me" gadget in Jira

Tags: jira

"**Assign to me**" gadget doesn't show **resolved** issues in the list. So, I don't want the users use(or see) this gadget in **JIRA (v6.4.11)**.

I searched in administration but I can't find a way to disable or remove this gadget. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Under the System tab (in Administration), look under **User Interface > System dashboard**.

From here, you can remove the **Assigned to Me** gadget from the default system dashboard.

Comment: Good idea. But I want no one can add "assign to me" to any user defined dashboard.